# Unable to CREATE DATABASE: error while processing file dmanage.bsq

Tags: oracle-12c

I want to create a DATABASE on my recently installed Oracle 12c so, after creating spfile and listener/tnsnames/sqlnet.ora for my instance, I call my CREATE DATABASE request :

```
CREATE DATABASE DBNAME
   USER SYS    identified by password
   USER SYSTEM identified by password
     MAXINSTANCES  1
     MAXLOGHISTORY 1
     MAXLOGFILES   20
     MAXLOGMEMBERS 4
     MAXDATAFILES  200
   CONTROLFILE REUSE
   DATAFILE
           '/[...]/system_01.dbf' SIZE 1000M REUSE
   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
   SYSAUX DATAFILE
           '/[...]/sysaux_01.dbf' SIZE 2000M REUSE
   UNDO TABLESPACE "UNDO" DATAFILE
           '/[...]/undo_01.dbf'     SIZE 2000M REUSE
   DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TMP" TEMPFILE
           '/[...]/tmp_01.dbf'       SIZE 2000M REUSE
            EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  UNIFORM SIZE 1M
   LOGFILE
       GROUP 1 ('/[...]/redo_1a.dbf',
                '/[...]/redo_1b.dbf') SIZE 100M REUSE,
       GROUP 2 ('/[...]/redo_2a.dbf',
                '/[...]/redo_2b.dbf') SIZE 100M REUSE,
   CHARACTER SET WE8ISO8859P15
   NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16 ;
```

And I get this error:

```
CREATE DATABASE DBNAME
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01519: error while processing file '?/rdbms/admin/dmanage.bsq' near line 22
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-19502: write error on file "/[...]/sysaux_01.dbf", block
number 640 (block size=8192)
ORA-27085: Message 27085 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA
Additional information: 1044480
Additional information: 1048576
Process ID: 23040
Session ID: 244 Serial number: 9021
```

The request at the line 22 of the dmanage.bsq file is:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE sysaux DATAFILE "D_SXFN"
  "D_SDSG" ONLINE FORCE LOGGING
/
```

What is the problem with my request?

Comment: `ORA-19502: write error on file ...` and `ORA-27085`, this may be a permission problem, or other OS issue (disk space full, or incorrect configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3924012), this error means I don't have enough space on my disk. I try the same request with lower size for my datafile and it works.

So, I have two solutions: adapt, in my request, the size of my datafiles or [extend my logical volume](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/).